# General solution of zeros of summation of two rational functions

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Let, $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ and $\frac{M(x)}{N(x)}$ be two rational functions consisting of polynominals ${P(x)},{Q(x)},{M(x)},{N(x)}$. The polyniminals are defined with respect to variable x. Now, if a rational function is formed by summation of the rational functions, does there exist a general way to evaluate the zeros of $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} + \frac{M(x)}{N(x)}$? If yes, where will the zeros of $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ and $\frac{M(x)}{N(x)}$ map to?

Edit 1: I know that, roots of $P(x)N(x)$ will be union of the roots of P(x) and N(x), and so on so forth for $Q(x)M(x)$. So, few possible roots can be calculated by taking the intersection of the roots of $P(x)N(x)$ and $Q(x)M(x)$. But I am not interested in them, I want solution in general.

Edit 2: What if, $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ is a Pade approximant of order (m,n)?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$
\frac{P}{Q}+\frac{M}{N}=\frac{PN+QM}{QN}
$$

so, if we know the roots of $P(x),Q(x),M(x),N(x)$, it is easy to find the roots of the denominator, but not ( in general) the roots of the numerator.

Comment: I knew that bit. the roots of the denominator will be the union of the roots of Q(x), and N(x). But, in general, I am interested in finding the roots of the numerator polynomial. Any suggestions? I have also edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular relation between the roots of two functions and their sum. Think of $f(x)+f(x)$, or $f(x)-f(x)$, or $f(x)+1$.

Furthermore, if $f$ and $g$ are polynomials only known by their roots, they are indeterminate to a constant factor and the roots of $\lambda f+\mu g$ can be anything.

Comment: That's true. I understand.